# UPDATE и SELECT помогите объединить

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите пожалуйста объединить запросы

```
UPDATE prohod SET (status = '0', time_vih='".$datev."', date_vih = '".$datey."') 
SELECT id, status, date_vih, time_vih FROM prohod WHERE propusk=0006 order by id desc limit 1
```

Comment: Что должно получиться в результате?

Comment: Кто мешает использовать мультизапрос?

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема в том, что нельзя просто взять и обновлять данные во время их вытаскивания.
Но есть отличные решения данного вопроса.

Конструкция SELECT * FROM ( SELECT ....) она позволяет обойти это правило.
Создается временная табличка, с которой sql уже может работать и не вызывать конфликта.
Просто оберните в еще один SELECT ваш запрос, и будет чудо)